# Theory or method on how to calculate the pressure needed to push a viscous fluid through a narrow slit

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, surface-tension, viscosity, glass

I need to calculate the minimum amount of pressure I need to apply to a piece of molten glass to **start** making it pass through a narrow slit - think 1 kg of glass and a 0.2 mm slit.

At this point I may assume that the temperature of the glass  is constant and that it is viscous enough to be modeled as a fluid (~800°C).

Is the viscosity the main factor? Should I worry about surface tension?
Since I'm only concerned about the necessary pressure to start the process of flowing through the slit, I dont think I need to worry about the non-Newtonian properties of glass, am I right?

Comment: The slightest amount of pressure difference will start it flowing through the slit.  You do not have to worry about surface tension, which will be negligible.  Do you know the equation for the pressure drop for steady flow of a viscous fluid through a slit?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No, I dont know that equation, can you help me out with it, a google search didnt yield any obvious results for anything like that.

Comment: Google "Viscous flow through a slit."